# Detecting Mouse Event over Multiple Graphics View

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have a class "SceneWindow" which inherits QGraphicsScene. I have a mouse move event which emits the current x and y position of the mouse on the scene.

In my main window class I have four graphicsview which I use to display different images. I have created four objects of the same graphicsscene class to set on the view. I want to detect on which of the graphics view my mouse currently is. 
How do I do it?
I tried using event filter in main class to detect the view but it is not helping. I tried it in the following way:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *f_object, QEvent *f_event)
{
  if(f_object == graphicsView && f_event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
  {
     qDebug() << "I am in Scene 1";
  }
```

Can someone please give a solution to this?

Thank You.

Comment: What means "...but it is not helping"? What you want to get and what you actually get?

Comment: I am not receiving the event for graphics view even when I move the mouse over graphics view.

Comment: Maybe it worth to try to install the event filter on QGraphicsView's viewport instead?

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. That does the work. Should I put it in the answer section or you will do it. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Making the answer from comment...

The problem is that you install the event filter on the `QGraphicsView`, however mouse events are handled by rather **viewport** than the view itself. Therefore, to make your event filter "catch" the mouse events you need to install it on the viewport:

```
graphicsView->viewport()->installEventFilter(filter);
```